Eclipse, VSCode, and Signal hang on start
Since yesterday (the only changes were sudo apt dist-upgrade and sudo snap refresh), several apps freeze forever / stop responding upon restarting the app - (Eclipse (via snap), VSCode (via apt/Microsoft), Signal (via snap)). Signal and VSCode hang on an empty screen, Eclipse on several actions, such as scrolling.
VSCode empty screen:

The processes cannot be killed (kill, kill -9, killall) (killall code -> pidof code lists 3 to 5 processes) or rather Eclipse remains displayed despite no process (pidof eclipse is empty). Shutdown of Kubuntu takes forever (must press the off button).
Reinstalling Eclipse or VSCode does nothing.
What can I do to find the problem / get more info / fix everything?
I checked the kernel logs. These seem like the most interesting messages:
... kernel: traps: WatchDogQueue[7496] trap int3 ip:701222d23def sp:7011b7dff5e0 error:0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.8000.5[701222cdb000+a2000]

... kernel: INFO: task WebKitWebProces:19436 blocked for more than 122 seconds.

